# How to execute the code after ShowDialog() in Winforms?

Tags: c#, windows

I have used ShowDialog() in Winforms to show screen and after ShowDialog() I have written timer event. So when we close the dialog box,the timer event gets called unless it is not getting executed.

Could anyone please help me by explaining this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

ShowDialog() is synchronous. So the code after ShowDialog() is not executed until the dialog is closed. So you could evaluate the DialogResult from the dialog after.

To solve the problem to execute things in parallel to the open dialog, you'd need to start your timer before the ShowDialog() or use Threading/BackgroundWorker.